# Three.js - How to combine objects into a single object/geometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

It seems some tutorials are outdated, and I'm having trouble combining my objects into a single piece for a performance boost:

```
var tmp1 = model.clone();
tmp1.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(tmp1);

var tmp2 = model.clone();
tmp2.position.set(1, 0, 0);
scene.add(tmp2);
```

Instead, I would like to combine tmp1 and tmp2 together, and use as a single object:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.merge(tmp1.geometry, tmp1.matrix);
geometry.merge(tmp1.geometry, tmp1.matrix);

scene.add ( geometry );
```

But it seems `THREE.Geometry()` is deprecated

Comment: Put the in a `Group`? https://threejs.org/docs/?q=group#api/en/objects/Group

Comment: @msbit I don't think `Group` necessarily combines it.. or is it virtually the same as merging?

Comment: No, that's just for grouping. From a bit of a look, perhaps `BufferGeometry` has basically replaced `Geometry` and would be worth a try?

Comment: @msbit Tried that as well, but the `.merge()` function doesn't work with it

`THREE.BufferGeometry.merge(): geometry not an instance of THREE.BufferGeometry`

Comment: Looks like you'll have to create the original model using `BufferGeometry` then you may be able to simply merge as above.

Comment: Is it really necessary to merge the two shapes? Like msbit said, putting shapes into a `Group` will allow you to move them together, and even set group visibility. What performance problem are you seeing when they are separate?